# Accessing Layout Elements without JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

The layout page that calls the @Renderbody() method has a navigation bar, and I want to add an orange border to the button that represents the page the user is currently on.  The only way I can think to do this is to add a class (.current or something) to the button on each individual page, but since the elements live in the _layout page, I can't change them per-page.  This is easy to do with JavaScript, but is there a way to do it using strictly HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Just because they creating the menu happens in _Layout doesn't mean that it cannot change on a page by page basis. You still have access to all the usual pipeline components whilst rendering _Layout. I can think of two methods that you could use, not sure which I prefer or if I even really like either of them, but they should show you that things are possible and perhaps you can think of a cleaner way to achieve it or someone else can think of a better way of doing it.

1. You could load something into the ViewData object in you action (or as part of a base controller or some generic code that is run for every action) that can then be fished out in the _Layout and used to add the class to the relevant button.
2. You could interrogate the Route object from within _Layout to figure out what page you where currently looking at and use that to add the class to the relevant button.

Hope this helps.

Cheers Mike